# lsof not showing what port a proc is listening on

Tags: unix, solaris, netstat, lsof

I have many processes on a box listening on several ports.
I am trying to map ports to pids.
The problem is that lsof is not telling me what ports belong to which process.

Given an apache listening on port 80, I can see it listening via netstat:
`user@host% netstat -an|grep LISTEN|grep 80`
`*.80                 *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN`

But when I try to map port 80 to a pid I get nothing:
`user@host% lsof -iTCP:80 -t`

When I try seeing what sockets that specific pid is using I get:
`user@host% lsof -lnP -p31 -a -i`
`COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE        DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME`
`libhttpd.  31        0   15u  IPv4 0x6002d970b80      0t0  TCP *:65535 (LISTEN)`

Notice the *:65535 in the NAME column.

Does anyone know why lsof is not reporting the port in use?

I am running as root.
I am using a mix of lsof and os versions:
lsof v4.77 on Solaris10 sparc
lsof v4.72 on Redhat4.2
etc

I know that linux solutions can use "netstat -p",
so I guess I'm only looking for why solaris isn't working,
but I find lsof is frequently silent and not showing me expected data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd rather use pfiles which is part of Solaris and supported by Sun, unlike lsof.

Its usage is slightly different as it expects a pid as argument but you can achieve what you want with something like:

```
pfiles $(pgrep libhttpd)
```

or even, if you don't know the process name:

```
pfiles /proc/*
```

Comment: `pfiles 31`  
shows me which ip:port it is bound to... that's likely to get me where I need to go...

Comment: oh dear, this is scary:
"[pfiles will] stop their target processes while inspecting them and reporting the results"
http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/816-0210/6m6nb7mh3?a=view
that sounds very very bad

Comment: Indeed, that might be an issue for processes with an extremely large number of open files.
Here is a nice alternative that doesn't stop processes: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/dtrace-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg02625.html